# java multi threading - how to synchronise

Tags: java, java-threads

I have a class with following method

```
public class Test {
    private List l1;
    public void send() {
         for (<type> x : l1) {
               //send to receivers and put a log in DB
          }
    }
}
```

This Test class is used by different threads which will fill the variable 'l1' with their own data and send them to receivers.
If I have to synchronize this to send data sequentially so that receivers get one full frame of data every time(without jumbling of data from different threads), should I synchronize on 'l1' or synchronize on the class Test.
I read the tutorials and samples but I still have this question.

Comment: Your code should at least show one of the options you cannot decide between.

Comment: Choosing your suitable synchronized collection and the synchronization strategy is not always trivial, it depends also on the rate of read / write operations, whether there are more reads than writes or vice versa. And... you want to synchronize not only your *send* method (basically your *read* operation against the collection *l1*) but also the method which writes into your collection *l1* (*write* operation): that method is missing / undisclosed in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should synchronize on the object that represents you "shared state" (l1 in this case); you must ensure that every insert/read operation is synchronized
so you must have a `synchronized(l1) {...}` block for `add` (and `remove`) call and one while sending:

```
public void send() {
     synchronized(l1) {
         for (<type> x : l1) {
           //send to receivers and put a log in DB
         }
     }
}
```

depending on you requirements you can also implement something more complex like:

```
public void send() {
     synchronized(l1) {
         List l2=new ArrayList(l1);
         //clear l1?
     }
     for (<type> x : l2) {
        //send to receivers and put a log in DB
     }
}
```

and allow a grater degree of concurrency